# How to find which style has been used in latex

Tags: msword

I have used word document to write my assignment but my university sent me the format of latex. I dont know about the latex, so is there any way where I can find which style the university needs (e.g. font style, size etc). I have the format in latex file but I have written all my document in word.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you received as "the format of latex". Is it a full-fledged template? It would definitely help if you edited your posting and included the contents of the format file you received.

Comment: Thank you David, I do not know about the latex at all and not sure how to include the detail of the format I have received. I just received the zip file.

Comment: currently it is more or less impossible to understand your question. You could at least show the list of filenames that are in the zip, add to your question.

Comment: If you have been given a class file for the thesis (this is what most university departments that support latex thesis will supply) then the class file _specifies_ the fonts so you as author do not need to know which fonts they are. So it is not clear what question you are asking or what you would do with an answer that gave a required font.

Comment: Actually I need to know which format they require, so that I adjust my word document according to that format.

Comment: a latex class file may specify dozens of fonts, for the main body, for section headings, for mathematics, etc, if you show the class contents someone may give you a summary but really it is unlikely to be a useful way to proceed. If the university accepts word documents they will (or should) have instructions for word styles as well as latex submission.

Comment: Thank you sir for your information. I will ask them if they have the format in word style?

Comment: Most probably  your template is compilable "as is" or after adding some dummy text. Just compile it, and you will see the format in the PDF. But depending on the complexity of the document, maybe it is  easier (even for you) copy and paste the whole text as plain text in the template and adapt it. For instance, in case of just text with some headers, it is a matter of few minutes search headers like  "1. Introduction"  and change it by or `\chapter{Introduction}` (or `\section{Introduction}` in case of article-like templates)  and compile it.